# Header's content is overlapped in Jquery mobile in IOS SDK8

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, cordova, jquery-mobile

After update my app to the current phone gap's version in **IOS SDK 8** I just noticed that there is a overlapping in the header, between the title and control group, that control group has inside two buttons, I tried using **data-mini="true"** to reduce the button's size but it doesn't work or at least looks like.

You can check the problem here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOtH7.png

**The Code:**

```
<div id="leyes-categoria-lv1-header" data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h3 class="titulo"></h3>
            <div data-type="horizontal" data-role="controlgroup" class="ui-btn-left ios-nav"> 
                <a data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" onclick="onBackKeyDown()">Volver</a>
                <a data-role="button" href="#leyes-inicio" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">leyes-inicio</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Stuff used:

- MAC OS Yosenite
- IOS SDK 8
- jquery.mobile-1.3.2
- phonegap 5.1.1 (lastest version at the moment)

How does i can avoid this behavior? cuz this only happens in my app's version for IOS and not for android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after testing on my html's code I noticed some strange css's rules(that happens when you are working in something done by other programmer :P ) that only affects my version of IOS something with previous version of phonegap did't happen(i dont know why).

**My solution**

Adjusted the margin-left and set text-overflow: ellipsis;